# Generic that implements an interface or is a double?

Tags: c#, generics, wrapper, primitive

Say I have this generic class:

```
abstract class Foo<T> where T : IBar
```

This is fine up to here, however I would like to also be able to pass `double` as well. Now I have been told that this is a bad idea and that the only way to solve this problem is to write a duplicate class handling the double case. I have also been told that toying with primitive types like this is not a good idea.

What I thought about doing was wrapping `double` in a class that implements `IBar`. This would allow me to use the wrapped double. I can for see some problems with usage of the class and I have again been told that wrapping primitive types for these kinds of purposes is a bad idea.

- What would be a good way to go around this?
- Is it time for me to reconsider using doubles?
- Should I just go with creating a separate duplicate class to handle doubles? (in my opinion this sounds as if I am not reusing).
- What is the rule of thumb (if there is one) when having to deal with primitives in a generic way?

The structs that are catagorised are `double` which we know of and a `BigRational` struct. This is a representation of a quotient between two `System.Numerics.BigInteger` members. Arithmetic is fully defined on this struct and what `Foo` is doing with `T` should be defined for `double` and `BigRational`.

Now the apposing reason is that these are *unrelated* and therefore it is *bad practice* to create an interface to unite them (not to mention wrapping the primitive in the first place).

My idea for the `IBar` interface was to have arithmetic as a requirement. Now in the future if I attempt to use `Foo` for other classes/structs that implement `IBar` it should be fine. **But I want `double` to work as well.** So now what I am looking for is a good reason to even wrap `double` in the first place and how this would coincide with good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would consider wrapping `double` in a *struct* rather than a class.

There's no way of saying "`T` must either be `double` or implement `IBar`" but wrapping a primitive value in a struct is entirely reasonable (assuming it actually makes sense for the meaning of `IBar`; we don't know anything about it at the moment).

Comment: I have been told (again) that it would be *bad practice* to create and interface `IBar` solely for the purpose of categorizing problematically unrelated classes/structs especially `double`. Now the reason I would like to do this in the first place is because intuitively they are similar. I shall add to the question giving more details.

Comment: @Alizter: When someone says not to do something that feels natural, demand an explanation. You shouldn't do things just because you've been told not to - that just propagates myths. (It's entirely possible that the person telling you not to has misunderstood something, for example.)

Comment: The explanation I received: "There is a fundamental difference between `double` and `BigRational` [See OP]. A double adds two doubles and returns a double a BigRational adds two BigRationals and returns a BigRational. An interface relating the two cannot be done as they return different things. This is the flaw."

Comment: @Alizter: Well that sounds like you want to make the interface generic as well. Then it could be `IAddable<T>` with a member of `T Add(T lhs, T rhs)`. Then your `double` wrapper would implement `IAddable<T>` and your `BigRational` struct would implement `IAddable<BigRational>`. They can still return different things with no issues.

Comment: It is all working. Thank you very much! However the struct wrapper for `double` felt a bit unstable (I don't know) so I stuck with a class.